# How to get the real totals (without the TOP) when I do a ms access report with the SELECT TOP 10 ....?

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

When I do a report I use the variable

> =sum([sell])

and the result here is the sum of TOP 10. My question is how do I show the result of the sum with all the elements, like the TOP 10 wouldn't exists?

SQL example:

```
 Select top 10 name, cust, sell from sales
```

In practice the query is monstrous, big and dirty:

```
SELECT top 125 COD_FAM, NOME_FAM, ID_VENDEDOR, NOME_VENDEDOR, ID_ZONA, CONTA_CLI, SUB_CONTA_CLI, NOME_CLI, SUM(VENDA1) AS VENDAS1, SUM(VENDA2) AS VENDAS2, ROUND(IIF(SUM(VENDA1)=0, 9999, ((SUM(VENDA2)-SUM(VENDA1)))/abs(SUM(VENDA1))*100), 2) AS PER_DIFF   FROM( SELECT quarter, month, COD_FAM, NOME_FAM, ID_VENDEDOR, NOME_VENDEDOR, ID_ZONA, CONTA_CLI, SUB_CONTA_CLI, NOME_CLI, VENDA AS VENDA1, 0 AS VENDA2 FROM STKQRY_VENDAS07_FAM_MONTH_VND_CLI_F1 WHERE year = '2012' AND Month between '00' and '05' UNION ALL SELECT quarter, month, COD_FAM, NOME_FAM, ID_VENDEDOR, NOME_VENDEDOR, ID_ZONA, CONTA_CLI, SUB_CONTA_CLI, NOME_CLI, 0 AS VENDA1, VENDA AS VENDA2 FROM STKQRY_VENDAS07_FAM_MONTH_VND_CLI_F1 WHERE year = '2013' AND Month between '00' and '05'  ) GROUP BY COD_FAM, NOME_FAM, ID_VENDEDOR, NOME_VENDEDOR, ID_ZONA, CONTA_CLI, SUB_CONTA_CLI, NOME_CLI HAVING (SUM(VENDA1) > 1000 OR SUM(VENDA2) > 1000) ORDER BY vendas2 desc
```

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: Updated with the query

Answer (score 0):

You need to join 2 queries like

```
SELECT TOP 10 Company, SUM(Sales) from MyTable Group By Company   --Query to get data for TOP 10
Union All
SELECT 'Grand Total', SUM(Sales) from MyTable  --Query to get the Grand total
```

Comment: But this would result in [top-10-sales]+[all-sales] which is not wrong.

Comment: My query for the report is just "select top 10 name, sales from table" the sum is made in the report in ms-access not in the sql..

Comment: `UNION` does not do any calculations. It just staks rows set after set. In Access you may need to create 2 Select queries and 1 Union query... Although I don't remember Access so well now.